# Cant properly import or get a specific container React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i've been trying to create component classes in one file and default export them into another file where they are imported and displayed in another component class (all for the sake of keeping my code clean)

But i am having problems getting the code to show up on the webpage i have built.

Here is the code in my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import user_Preference_Nav from './topUserPreferences.js';  // import from the external file

    class FavouritesOptionsModule extends Component {
      render() {
      return (
        <div>
           <user_Preference_Nav />
        </div>
  
  
     )
  }
}


class FavouriteSection extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{flex: '0 1 48.5%'}}>
        <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>
        <div style={{...StyleFrame}}>
          <FavouritesOptionsModule/> //the outer container for the imported classes gets instantiated here.. this all gets shown correctly, its just the content within this instantiated class that isint properly shown.
          <div style={{...StyleItemList}}>
             <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
            <FavouriteItem/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
} // and there is another class that gets instantiated as an outer component to this one, but i feel like that info is redundant as all outer containers display correctly its just the "<user_Preference_Nav />" from the "topUserPreferences.js" file that isint properlt shown...
```

and here are the component classes in the external file "topUserPreferences.js"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";


class user_Preference_Nav extends Component{

  render(){

    return(

  <div id="user-pref-main">

    <user_Preference_Slider />
    <user_Preference_Button />
    <user_Preference_Timeform />

  </div>

     )
   }
}

export default user_Preference_Nav //the default export


class user_Preference_Slider extends Component{



    render(){

        function valuetext(value) {
        return `${value}objects`;
      }

return(
  <div className="slider">
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        Limit
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={30}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        step={1}
        marks
        min={1}
        max={50}
    />
  </div>

)
}
}


class user_Preference_Button extends Component {

render() {

return(
  <div className="send_Container">
    <Button className="go_Button" variant="outlined">
      Go!
    </Button>
  </div>

    )
   }
}


class user_Preference_Timeform extends Component {

render() {



    return(

  <div className="timeForm">
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      {/* <FormLabel component="legend">labelPlacement</FormLabel> */}
      <RadioGroup
        row
        aria-label="position"
        name="position"
        defaultValue="top"
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="top"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="Long"
          labelPlacement="top"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="start"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="Medium"
          labelPlacement="top"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="bottom"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="Short"
          labelPlacement="top"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  </div>


    )
}

}
```

Im expecting these containers to show up on the page but all that happens is the actual tag itself
"<user_Preference_Nav />" gets shown as if it were text and not the actual code within it...

Bear with me on this as i am  a newbie to react, and this is most definetly a newbie question
I also understand that there are a lot of components within components... so if ye have any issues understanding my flow of code do let me know.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined components – as opposed to standard HTML components – [need to start with an uppercase letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). It's how React knows whether or not you want to use your own component or use a standard HTML tag.

Your component `user_Preference_Nav` starts with a lowercase letter so React will render it as the HTML string `<user_Preference_Nav />`, which is obviously not what you want.

Rename the component to

```
class User_Preference_Nav extends Component {
  //  ^
  // ...
}
```

and it should work as expected.